# Why is my app closing automatically when I click a button?

Tags: r, shiny

I am recently working on a shiny app for my project but it closes automatically whenever I click the search button. I am working on finding hotels by filtering countries, prices and star ratings on a map view, with a hotel description panel on the main panel so viewers can check out the description after clicking on one hotel. How can I fix this?

Below is my code:

sample code:

```
countyCode <- c("AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL")
countyName <- c("Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania")
cityCode <- c(106078, 106078, 106078, 106078, 106078, 106078, 106078, 106078, 106078, 106078, 106078, 106078, 106078)
cityName <- c("Albanien", "Albanien", "Albanien", "Albanien", "Albanien", "Albanien", "Albanien", "Albanien", "Albanien", "Albanien", "Albanien", "Albanien", "Albanien")
HotelCode <- c(1003300, 1003301, 1003302, 1003303, 1003325, 1015185, 1016188, 1016189, 1017483, 1032158, 1032161, 1040270, 1040270)
HotelName <- c("De Paris Hotel", "Hotel Green", "Theranda Hotel", "Seven Hotel", "Viktoria", "Bel Conti Hotel", "Pik Loti Hotel", "Hotel Parlamenti", "Victoria", "MonarC Hotel", "White Dream Hotel", "Capital Tirana Hotel", "Capital Tirana Hotel")
HotelRating <- c("FourStar", "FourStar", "ThreeStar", "ThreeStar", "ThreeStar", "FourStar", "ThreeStar", "ThreeStar", "ThreeStar", "FourStar", "FourStar", "ThreeStar", "ThreeStar")
Address <- c("Nr. 7 Brigada Viii Street Tirane", "Rruga Kavajes. Kombinat Km 2. Vaqarr VaqarrTirana", "Rr. Andon Zako Cajupi Villa 6 & 7 Villa 6 & 7Tiran�Shqip�ri", "KAVAJA STREET, CLOSE TURKISH AMBASSY TIRANA", "Rruga E Elbasanit Km 4 Sauk SaukTirana", "Shkembi i Kavajes L13 Durres", "Rruga Petro Nini Luarasi Tirana", "Rruga Jeronim De Rada 75 1001 Tirana", "Dibra Street 331 331 Tirana", "Intersection. Rr. George W. Bush Road And Blvd. Zhan D Ark Tirana", "Rr. Elbasanit pasi kalon Pallatin e Brigadaveperballe shkolles se Policise ne SaukTirana", "Rruga Qemal Stafa Next to General Prosecution Office Next to The General Prosecution Office1016 Tirana", "Rruga Qemal Stafa Next to General Prosecution Office Next to The General Prosecution Office1016 Tirana")
Attractions <- c(NA, NA, "Skanderbeg Square: within 500 metre", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Distances are displayed to the nearest 0.1 mile and kilometer.", "Distances are displayed to the nearest 0.1 mile and kilometer.", "Distances are displayed to the nearest 0.1 mile and kilometer.", "Distances are displayed to the nearest 0.1 mile and kilometer.", "Distances are displayed to the nearest 0.1 mile and kilometer.")
Description <- c("Hotel de Paris is a charming boutique hotel that offers stylish rooms and a large courtyard garden perfect for enjoying a relaxing meal outdoors. A private bar with an open fireplace is suitable for a night cap. Rooms and suites at De Paris are luxuriously furnished and offer air-conditioning, a minibar and a work desk. Every room has a flat-screen TV with satellite channels. Private bathroom provides a hairdryer, a bathrobe and free toiletries. The hotel is situated in the elegant area of the city full of bars and restaurants, and just a few steps away from the main institutions such as Parliament, Palace of Congress, Opera House, Art Gallery and Main Boulevard. Ironing, laundry and dry cleaning services are available. The reception is open 24 hours a day and breakfast buffet is served each day. The nearest bus stop is only 50 metres from the property, while the Main Bus Station can be reached in 300 metres. Tirana Airport is 15 km away.", "Located in a suburb of Tirana, Hotel Green is just a couple of steps from the national road Tirana-Durres. Surrounded by a garden, the hotel offers an on-site bar and restaurant serving traditional and international dishes. All rooms are air-conditioned and feature free Wi-Fi, satellite TV and a private bathroom with shower. Guests can park their car for free on site. Breakfast is served at the hotel restaurant each day. The front desk is open 24 hours a day and room service is available. The centre of Tirana is 7.4 km away. The famous Blloku Area, an upmarket part of town known as a shopping destination and entertainment site, can be reached in 3 km. Boutiques, shops, restaurants, trendy bars, pubs, and cafes can be found in abundance. Main Bus Station is 2 km away, while the Train Station can be reached in 2.3 km. Tirana Airport is 18 km away.", "Set in Tirana, 1.2 km from Skanderbeg Square, Theranda
```

I have cleaned up some parts of my data:

```
hotels <- hotels %>%
  mutate(HotelStars = case_when(
    HotelRating == "All" ~ 6,
    HotelRating == "FiveStar" ~ 5,
    HotelRating == "FourStar" ~ 4,
    HotelRating == "ThreeStar" ~ 3,
    HotelRating == "TwoStar" ~ 2,
    HotelRating == "OneStar" ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ NA_integer_  # Handle other cases
  ))

generate_random_price <- function(star) {
  if (star == 1) {
    return(runif(1, min = 20, max = 60))
  } else if (star == 2) {
    return(runif(1, min = 60, max = 100))
  } else if (star == 3) {
    return(runif(1, min = 100, max = 200))
  } else if (star == 4) {
    return(runif(1, min = 200, max = 300))
  } else if (star == 5) {
    return(runif(1, min = 300, max = 400))
  } else if (star == 6) {
    return(runif(1, min = 400, max = 800))
  } else {
    return(NA)  # Handle other cases
  }
}

# Apply the function to generate random prices based on star ratings
hotels <- hotels %>%
  mutate(HotelStars = case_when(
    HotelRating == "All" ~ 6,
    HotelRating == "FiveStar" ~ 5,
    HotelRating == "FourStar" ~ 4,
    HotelRating == "ThreeStar" ~ 3,
    HotelRating == "TwoStar" ~ 2,
    HotelRating == "OneStar" ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ NA_integer_  # Handle other cases
  ),
  AveragePricePerNight = sapply(HotelStars, generate_random_price))

# Round the AveragePricePerNight column to whole numbers
hotels$AveragePricePerNight <- round(hotels$AveragePricePerNight)

colnames(hotels)[which(names(hotels) == "countyCode")] <- "countryCode"
colnames(hotels)[which(names(hotels) == "countyName")] <- "countryName"
# Replace NA values with "NIL" in hotels$Description
hotels$Description <- ifelse(is.na(hotels$Description), "NIL", hotels$Description)

# Convert hotels$Description to character vector
hotels$Description <- as.character(hotels$Description)

# Define UI
    ui <- fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Hotel Explorer"),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("countryName", "Select Country", choices = unique(hotels$countryName)),
        dateRangeInput("h_date", "Select Dates", start = Sys.Date(), end = Sys.Date() + 7),
        sliderInput("AveragePricePerNight", "Price Range", min = 0, max = 1000, value = c(0, 500)),
        sliderInput("HotelStars", "Hotel Stars Ratings", min = 0, max = 10, value = c(0, 10)),
        actionButton("search_button", "Search")
    ),
      mainPanel(
       tabsetPanel(
         id = "tabset",
         tabPanel("Map View", leafletOutput("h_map")),
         tabPanel("Hotel Details",
                 textOutput("hotel_name"),
                 textOutput("description"),
                 dataTableOutput("hotel_info"))
      )
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$search_button, {
    filtered_data <- reactive({
      subset(hotels, 
             countryName == input$countryName & 
             HotelStars >= input$HotelStars[1] & 
             HotelStars <= input$HotelStars[2] &
             AveragePricePerNight >= input$AveragePricePerNight[1] &
             AveragePricePerNight <= input$AveragePricePerNight[2])
    })

    # Render the map
    output$h_map <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet() %>%
        addTiles() %>%
        addMarkers(data = filtered_data(),
                   ~Longitude, ~Latitude,
                   popup = ~HotelName)
    })

    # Display hotel information in the main panel
    output$hotel_name <- renderText({
      if (nrow(filtered_data()) > 0) {
        filtered_data()$HotelName[1]
      } else {
        "No hotels found"
      }
    })

    output$description <- renderText({
     if (nrow(filtered_data()) > 0) {
        description <- filtered_data()$Description[1]
        if (is.na(description)) {
          description <- "NIL"
        }
        description
      } else {
        ""
      }
    })

    output$hotel_info <- renderDataTable({
      filtered_data()
    })
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)`
```

I had tried to run and edit my codes multiple times to ensure it aligns with my dataset(hotels.csv). It managed to work for the first time but it shuts down everytime afterwards.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Nesting inside an observer might be your issue.  Remove `observeEvent(input$search_button, {...})`.  Instead, use `filtered_data <- eventReactive(input$search_button, {...})`

Comment: I've never seen a time when nesting `observe` within `reactive` or vice versa was necessary, and too often it behaves differently than desired. I might be wrong in this, but nobody (over several years) has offered a counterpoint, so ... "never" nest reactive blocks. Sometimes the inner reactive block will do okay on its own, sometimes they need shoring up with logic, _often_ you need to think about what should trigger what and go from there.

Comment: Having said that, arins, what is it you need to happen when you next `reactive(.)` inside an `observeEvent`? If you want to update the filtered data only on button press, do something like `filtered_data <- eventReactive(input$search_button, subset(hotels, ...))`.

Comment: Welcome to SO, arins! I can't test the rest of your app without sample data, if you need more help, please [edit] your question and add sample data to a [code block]. If the data is small enough, you paste the output from `dput(hotels)`, though if it's larger please subset to just what we need to get the point across. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 , [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for notes on "reproducible questions". Thanks, and good luck!

Comment: @r2evans hello, thank you for your help! I have really been struggling as i’m really new to this programme. I have added a sample data set as the original csv that I use is pretty big. do lmk if there is anyth i can do thank you!

Comment: It's a start, but it is incomplete and sporadic. For instance, your `Description` ends without closing quotes or closing paren. Also, the lengths of those vectors range from 3 to 13. Because of that, we cannot make `hotels` as a frame like it should be. Please replace that with the output from `dput(head(hotels,10))`.

Comment: @r2evans hi, i’m not too sure what do you mean, will it be okay if you can give an example thank you

Comment: I don't know how I can be any clearer. Your current sample data is not usable, it is both a parsing error and cannot be made into a `data.frame`. Examples? The first two links I provided a few comments ago walk through many demonstrations of the use of `dput`, `data.frame`, and `read.table` for providing usable unambiguous sample data.